# Can Geany be used to Debug C++

Tags: c++, linux, ide, opensuse

Recently I shifted from Eclipse CDT to Geany for my C++ coding work, because of its simplicity. Can it be used to Debug C++. If no, Which other IDE on openSuse can be used for C++ debugging.

Answer (score 4):

See [here](http://plugins.geany.org/geanygdb.html) for information regarding GeanyGDB plugin.

Other IDEs that can be used to debug C++ include Anjuta and QtCreator.

Answer (score 0):

The GNU Debugger (GDB) for C/C++ can be used in Geany via Geany's [Debugger plugin](http://plugins.geany.org/debugger.html).